# Java -> including robot class in eclipse

Tags: java, class, include, awtrobot

I would like to work with this robot class :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

for generating native system input´s, thats why i created this file:

```
import java.awt.Robot;

public class MouseClass {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Robot robot = new Robot();

            // SET THE MOUSE X Y POSITION
            robot.mouseMove(300, 550);

 }
}
```

but i got this error-msg:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: robot/robot_v1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: robot.robot_v1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I thought, the awt.robot is already integrated in eclipse? ok if not..i dont know where to download this robot-class, the only page i found is:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Robot.java

but thats "Robot.java" and the error-message doent change when i include this in my "src".

Any advices how i can use this robot-class?

SOLVED ,but:

i get a compilation problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at robot.robot_v1.main(robot_v1.java:5)
```

For this line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

do i have to change name´s here as well in this case?

greetings

=> SOLDED with package robot;

Comment: are you sure you are not running some of your old code? by any chance your old version of your class was names robot_1 and it was in robot package?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? my workspace: robot/src/robot/robot_v1.java is that wrong?

Comment: java file should have same name as class, so as you have your class named `MouseClass` in `robot_v1.java` file, it can't find and load your class

Comment: yea u were right! vote up! but i get an compilation problem than, updated my question above, could you refer to it?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not related to Robot class at all. There is mismatch between your java file name and class name.

Your java class as you meantion in comment is `robot/robot_v1.java` and your class name is `MouseClass`. To make it work, all what you need to do is change your class name to be same as  file which will be `robot_v1` and as it is not in default package, you need to add at beginning of your file package definition, which will be for this case `package robot;`

Comment: yea totally forgotten, thanks! could you refer to the compilation-problem as well? would be really nice! greetings

Comment: @user3297073 and what is a problem exactly? i'm asking as you said solved after you explained compilation problem